# Order a collection of objects in the view with Grails

Tags: grails, collections

I'm having a problem when when I try to display a collection of objects in a view, they are being returned in a random order which differs each time i refresh the page.

Heres an example:

```
class Author{
    ...
    static hasMany = [books:Book]
}
class Book{
    ...
    static belongsTo = [author:Author]
}
```

In one of the author's views, I want to do something like:

```
<g:each in="${authorInstance.books}" var="book">
    //render book template or whatever...
</g:each>
```

When i do this, the collection of books returned is in a different order each time. How can I simply order the collection by ID each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to sort this collection. It all depends on where you want the sorting done.

First, you can define a default order for the collection in your domain:

```
class Author {
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    static mapping = {
        books sort: 'id', order: 'asc'
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could sort the collection in the GSP:

```
<g:each in="${authorInstance.books.sort{it.id}}" var="book">
    //render book template or whatever...
</g:each>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks Joshua. Both methods seem to work perfectly!